# 'Global' may not respond to '+setShow'

Tags: iphone

hai
   I am new iphone. In my application there is warning 'Global' may not respond to '+setShow'
   [Global setShow:True]; Please help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your Global.h file declare setShow method

Answer (score 0):

You have to give much more information if you want answers in this site...From what I understand this is what you want..

In Global.h file...

```
@interface Globals : NSObject {

}
+(void)setShow:(BOOL)show;
@end
```

In Global.m file

```
@implementation Globals
BOOL showStatus     =   false;

+(void)setShow:(BOOL)show{
    showStatus      =   show;
}
@end
```

And in whatever file you want this function, include Global.h.

```
#import "Globals.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `setShow:(BOOL)arg` in `Globel.h`, not `show()`

Comment: Yes you was right. I declared it and my warning also gone. Thanks a lot.